# JS Detect the action of scrolling even if already at bottom/top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, mouseevent

I'm using jquery.nicescroll and binding scroll event to detect when the scroll has reached the bottom but my problem is JS only detects scroll event **only IF** user can actually scroll. Which means, that if I have reached the bottom of the div and actually scroll down, JS doesn't bind scroll event.

My goal would be to set a timer when user reaches the bottom of the div and if they scroll again (after the timer) it would fire a function. But I don't want that function to be fired when user reaches the bottom (imagine your are scrolling down to read the end of the page and **after that**, you scroll again to go to another section of the page). I need to time the action to make sure the function doesn't fire because of "too many scroll" to go to the bottom of the page. I need to know the user already is at the bottom and scrolled again after a while.

Anyway, the thing I'm looking for is a way to detect the mouse's roll/scroll **even** when you can't actually scroll more. Just the action of scrolling, not the actual scrolling.

Comment: Try the `wheel` event (different browsers previously implemented this differently, but try `wheel` in the first instance).  Don't forget to also check for `space`, `pagedown` and `cursor/arrow down`.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m , I'll have a look right now !

Comment: That's weird, I can find this link that uses mousewheel event but nothing on the jquery documentation. It doesn't seem to work when binding mouswheel on a div, only $(window)

Comment: This might help: https://jsfiddle.net/a1co6xm7/1/

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the link I found before but with wheel, not mouswheel. I think I'll find my way with this. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The modern event is `wheel`.  It will only be raised even if the div can't be scrolling added the wrapper to give it somewhere to scroll, but not needed - see update: https://jsfiddle.net/45b9gnx6/ with #d3 not inside a wrapper but still receives the event.  Note: this won't work with mobile devices that don't have a wheel.

Comment: Ugh - terrible wording above - it will still be raised even if the div can't scroll.